# Differentiate --> I'm trying to differentiate but am having a hard time -- any pointers appreciated

Tags: calculus, derivatives

here is my poor attempt 
https://imgur.com/a/fX75
$f(x) = \log \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x}{\sqrt{x^1 + 1} + x}$

Comment: The link is broken. Try using the image insertion tool instead.

Comment: Is the power in the denominator $x^{1}$ or did you mean $x^{2}$?

Comment: Give the image web link.

Comment: If she had meant $x$ she would not have written $x^1$. Therefore we may as well assume that she meant $x^2$ and left it for us to find that out. This then will lead to a simple result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \log \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x}=$$

$$\log (\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x)-log(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x)$$

$$ \frac {d}{dx} \log (\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x)= $$

$$\frac {x- \sqrt {x^2+1}}{x^2+1-x \sqrt {x^2+1}}      $$

Similarly $$ \frac {d}{dx} \log (\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x)= $$

$$\frac {x+ \sqrt {x^2+1}}{x^2+1+x \sqrt {x^2+1}} $$

$$ f'(x)=\frac {x- \sqrt {x^2+1}}{x^2+1-x \sqrt {x^2+1}}-  \frac {x+ \sqrt {x^2+1}}{x^2+1+x \sqrt {x^2+1}} =2x-2\sqrt {x^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

by the chain and power rule we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{\left(x+\sqrt{x+1}\right)
   \left(\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-1}{x+\sqrt{x+1}}-
   \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x+1}}+1\right)
   \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)}{\left(x+\sqrt{x+1}\right)^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}$$
this Can be simplified

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sinh^{-1}x$. Then $x=\sinh y$, so 
$$1=\cosh yy^{\prime}=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2y}y^{\prime}=\sqrt{1+x^2}y^{\prime}$$
$$y^{\prime}=\frac d{dx}\sinh^{-1}x=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
On the other hand,
$$x=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}2$$
So $e^{2y}-2xe^y-1=0$. Solving for $e^y$,
$$e^y=x\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
Because $e^y>0$.
Then
$$y=\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)=\sinh^{-1}x$$
Also
$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)=x^2+1-x^2=1$$
So
$$\begin{align}\ln\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}&=\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)-\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\\
&=\ln\left[\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)^{-1}\right]-\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\\
&=-2\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)=-2\sinh^{-1}x\end{align}$$
So
$$\frac d{dx}\ln\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}=-2\frac d{dx}\sinh^{-1}x=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
**EDIT** It has become clear that what was desired was
$$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}\ln\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{\sqrt{x+1}+x}&=\frac d{dx}\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)-\frac d{dx}\ln\left(\sqrt{x+1}+x\right)\\
&=\frac{\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}-\frac{\frac1{2\sqrt{x+1}}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+x}\\
&=\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)}-\frac{1+2\sqrt{x+1}}{2\sqrt{x+1}\left(\sqrt{x+1}+x\right)}\\
&=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\frac{\left(1+2\sqrt{x+1}\right)\left(\sqrt{x+1}-x\right)}{2\sqrt{x+1}\left(x+1-x^2\right)}\\
&=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\frac{x+2+(1-2x)\sqrt{x+1}}{2\sqrt{x+1}\left(x+1-x^2\right)}\end{align}$$